# Defining IFESLE in arena

Tags: if-statement, arena-simulation

I am using Arena simulation software. I need to define "if" in the expression section of the Process Module. I could not find any instruction to define "ifelse" function.

Answer (score 2):

I never found IF statement in Arena simulation.

But don't worry. There is workaround with using expressions.

According to official Documentation:

> Logical Expression Evaluation
>
> ASSIGN: InventoryLevel = 50 *
>   (SystemStatus==Early) +
>               30 * (SystemStatus==Late);
>
> Assign InventoryLevel a value of 50 if the variable SystemStatus is
>   equal to Early (logical expressions evaluate to 1 for TRUE, 0 for
>   FALSE). If SystemStatus equals Late, assign InventoryLevel to 30. If
>   neither is true, assign SystemStatus equal to 0. This single ASSIGN
>   block may have been used to replace a BRANCH block (to check the value
>   of SystemStatus) and two ASSIGN blocks (to assign the correct value).